# Getting specific data from a json file discord.js

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I am doing a bot in discord and I would like to read some information or message from a json file and then compare it in js to make everything more neat and basically create a list of commands in a json file, but I have problems reading some fields from my json file, when I go to read my json file it shows me all the content, how could I get a text string of what is for example in the greetings-questions section
Here is my code, it shows me everything in my json, pls help me im stuck

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const FileJson =require ("./bot.json"); //this is my json fro a want to get the information
const fs = require('fs');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`bot ready as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });


  client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return; 

        fs.readFile('bot.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            const _msgs = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 6);
            message.channel.send(_msgs );
          
        });

    });
      
    


    client.login("here is the key of my bot");
```

This is what is in my json file which is "bot" I wanna get the content from Greeting/questions to comparete it with what people in my discord ask to then answer them

```js
{   "contenido":
    {
           "Greetings":[
            {"questions": ["Hi", "hello"]},
            {"answers": ["Hey, how are you?", "What's up?"]}
        ],
                          
            "goodbyes": [
            {"questions":["see you"]},
            {"answers":["see you"]}              
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Want to clear something up here; are you inquiring how you would access a specific value from the json?

Comment: Yes, that's my question, Im having problems getting acces to a specific value from my json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i just wanted to say that I just figured out and to people who have the same problem I had, this is the anwser I hpoe it helps you

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const bot= require ('./bot.json'); //this is my json from a want to get the information


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`bot ready as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });



    client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return; 
    
        var palabras=bot.contenido.Greetings;
        var questionss= palabras[0].questions;
        var answerss= palabras[1].answers; //the number 1 define to the array number 1 in the file json, so that's why "answers" is 1 and "questions" is 0
        
        var aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*(answerss.length)); //here a random to get a random phrase from the json file

        console.log(answerss[aleatorio]);
        
           });
    


    client.login("here is the key of my bot");
```

That's what I was trying to do, get information from a Json File, you can add more answers and it will works